# Extend a protocol with generic associatedtype

Tags: swift, generics, enums, swift-protocols, associated-types

Let's say we have a protocol defined as:

```
protocol PAT {
    associatedtype Element
}
```

and I also have an enum(typical Result) defined as:

```
enum Result<Value> {
    case success(Value)
    case error(Error)
}
```

Now I want to add an extension to `PAT` when `Element` is `Result<Value>` but compiler can not determine `Value` hence triggers a compile error indicating "reference to generic requires argument".

here's the code for extension:

```
extension Pat where Element == Result {
}
```

Comment: Good question. I think it's possible to do `where Element == Result<Int>` or something, but I'm not sure it's possible to do it for any Result type while remaining generic over Value. One option would be to make Result conform to some other protocol, then you could say `where Element: OtherProto`.

Comment: @jtbandes Yep `Result<Int>` works, but conforming to another protocol is not working either. I mean it works in some cases but it wont if you methods or variables want to work with `Value`. it sais: "Value can only be used as concrete or generic parameter"

Comment: What exactly do you want to do in the extension?

Comment: @jtbandes Well my real use-case is in using RxSwift.Observables. I want to add methods to `ObservableType` (a protocol with associated-type) when ObservableType.E is Result<Value> to map and filter sequence into values or errors only.

Comment: @jtbandes But it can be generalized to other use-cases as well. for example having a `Collection<Result<Value>>` trying to convert it into values or errors only. instead of filtering and mapping them each time using them, having a method that does that for you will really make code cleaner don't you think?

Comment: @jtbandes well, i think i'm doing something wrong here. conforming to another protocol sounds really promising and that's why i tried it even before posting. by it gives me exactly the error i said earlier but it's done here https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt/blob/master/Source/RxSwift/unwrap.swift !!

Comment: That's a little bit different because they are constraining E to be a PAT (Optionable), not a generic type.

Comment: @jtbandes well it's sad that code wasn't working because of stupid `Element == Resultable`. (Resultable is that other protocol). changed `==` to `:` silly mistake . Well I think this is the only way to do it, but the boiler plate is that you have to define a protocol (that some other protocol) each time you want to do such thing. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create another protocol with associatedType to wrap Result in it.

```
protocol Resultable {
    associatedType ValueType
    var isSuccess: Bool { get }
    var value: ValueType? { get }
}
```

and make Result extend Resultable:

```
extension Result: Resultable {
    typealias ValueType = Value
    var isSuccess: Bool { ... }
    var value: ValueType? { ... }
}
```

and extend `PAT` using `Resultable`:

```
extension PAT where Element: Resultable {
    // in here you have access to Resultable.ValueType
}
```

## Note

make sure writing `Element: Resultable` not `Element == Resultable`. This was the reason my code wasn't working in the first place.